# How to Change bootstrap 4 carousal speed on clicking arrow?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

Hi i am developing an application in bootstrap 4. The default bootstrap carousal  speed is too fast when i click on arrow, images are sliding too fast from left to right on arrow click.

I want to change the speed of slide when clicking on the arrow.

Here is my slider HTML:

```
<div id="carousel-area">
    <div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="img/slider/bg-1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Ultimate Solution for Your Website</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/slider/bg-2.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Ultimate Solution for Your Website</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/slider/bg-3.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Ultimate Solution for Your Website</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="lnr  lnr-arrow-left"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="lnr  lnr-arrow-right"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use CSS to change the speed of the `transition-duration` on the `.carousel-item`. For example, here is 2 seconds...

```
.carousel-item {
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/M24LEPlrMU